# How to update a variable from a jQuery function inside a .$getJSON Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, getjson

Giving this method, I declare a variable "answer" that will contain a String value. Then I call a getJSON method. I want to update the mentioned variable inside that method:

```
function verificarRespuestasAjax(pregunta, pinId, respuesta, index){
        var answer = pregunta;
        $.getJSON("../usuarios/comparar_respuestas_JSON", {pinId: pinId, preguntaId: pregunta, respuesta: respuesta.val() }, function(verifRespuestas){
            if(verifRespuestas){
                $("#mensajeError"+index).remove();
                answer += 'true';
            }else{
                if (!$("#mensajeError"+index).length > 0)
                    $(respuesta).after('<em id="mensajeError'+index+'">*La respuesta no coincide</em>');
                answer += 'false';
            }

        });
        return answer;
    }
```

How should I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did update the variable.  The only issue here is that the `getJSON` call is asynchronous.  At the time the `alert()` executes, the function callback for `getJSON` has not been called.

You will want to put your `alert(answer)` code in a function that you call from your JSON callback.

```
function verificarRespuestasAjax(pregunta, pinId, respuesta, index){
  var answer = pregunta;
  $.getJSON("../usuarios/comparar_respuestas_JSON", {pinId: pinId, preguntaId: pregunta, respuesta: respuesta.val() }, function(verifRespuestas){
    // .... snip ....
    completed();
  });
  answer += 'true';
  function completed() {
    alert( answer );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks gnarf!I'll try it! Could you take a look at the edited question? I deleted the line: answer += 'true';
How could I return that variable instead calling the alert method?

Comment: @Nord you don't - you use a callback function as an argument to `verificarRespuestasAjax` - you call it when you have your answer.  Welcome to asynchronous thinking.

Answer (score 3):

AJAX calls are asynchronous. Any code that should run after the response has been received needs to be in the success callback (or a function called by that callback).